# Guardfile's spork block expects a cucumber environment to exist... should it?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, cucumber, spork

I've got guard, spork, cucumber and rspec working away on my system. All my specs and features run nicely but one thing puzzles me.

When I run `guard init spork`, the Guardfile that is created contains the following:

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'cucumber' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
```

But this causes an error because I do not have a cucumber.rb file in my enironments folder. So to get this working I change the code to

```
guard 'spork', :cucumber_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' }, :rspec_env => { 'RAILS_ENV' => 'test' } do
```

Now my question is, why does guard/spork subsume that my application would have a cucumber.rb file in config/environments? Should I be running cucumber in it's own environment? Should I create a cucumber.rb file by hand? I'd have thought that `rails g cucumber:install` would have done that for me if it was so important.

Using the latest released versions of cucumber, rspec and guard-* gems

Comment: guard-spork gem has now been updated to incorporate this change

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason is that in earlier versions of cucumber, the `cucumber:install` generator actually created its own cucumber environment. This is no longer the case in the later versions of the gem, but the guard-spork gem still assumes the RAILS_ENV is cucumber instead of test. I use the same gem and made the same configuration change and everything is working as I would expect.